# commutative algebras without maximal ideals

Tags: commutative-algebra

Let $A$ be a commutative complex algebra and let $J$ denote the intersection of all maximal ideals in $A$ (if any; otherwise put $J:=A$).
Then $J$ is an algebra again.  Does $J$ admit maximal ideals? (It does not admit modular maximal ideals; these are maximal ideals $M$ for which $J/M$ is unital).

Answer (score 2):

It depends what $A$ is.  For instance, if $A=\mathbb{C}$, then $J=0$ has no maximal ideals.  But if $A=\mathbb{C}[x]/(x^3)$ the unique maximal ideal of $A$ is $J=(x)$, in which $(x^2)$ is a maximal ideal.